# Autohotkey: Replace a text with an icon

Tags: autohotkey

How can I replace a text with icon, just as a starter replacing **(y)** with a **thumbs-up icon** (like in FB)

So something like

```
(y)::.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing informations about the scenario where you're working in. Since you have mentioned 'Facebook' I believe you'll need Javascript instead of AutoHotKey. So, here's the two steps to switch letters by icons in a HTML page using Javascript. I hope it can enlighten your ideas:

1- Incorporate an icon library in your HTML's head like `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icon‌​s" rel="stylesheet">` (there's other options besides Google's one around the web)

2- Use Javascript to replace every expression like `(Y)` by the icon's library code such as `<i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i>`

Working snippet:

```js
function replace(){

var box = document.getElementById('box');
var str = box.value;
  
var filterok = str.replace(/\(Y\)/gi, "<i class='material-icons'>thumb_up</i>");  
var filtersmile= filterok.replace(/\=\)/gi, "<i class='material-icons'>&#xE24E;</i>");  
var filterHHH= filtersmile.replace(/HHH/gi, "<i class='material-icons'>favorite</i>");
  
 document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = filterHHH; 
}
```

```css
body {
background: lavender;  
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body onload="javascript: replace()">

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" oninput="replace()" id=box>
Every (Y) and =) and HHH inserted here will be substituted by a match icon.
</textarea>
<br>
<span id=target></span>
</body>
```

*ps: The `g` on `StringReplace` stands for 'global' while `gi` stands for 'global + case insensitive'.*

*ps2: The `\` are used to scape the special chars used on the icons call.*

*ps3: [Google Material Icons List](https://material.io/icons/)*

**If you mean to use AutoHotKey to edit the HTML code of a webpage instead, the way to do the same as the example above with AutoHotKey instead of Javascript would be:**

```
FileRead, filevar, page.html

symbolA:="(y)"
symbolB:="=)"
symbolC:="HHH"

StringReplace, filevar, filevar, %symbolA%, <i class='material-icons'>thumb_up</i>, All
StringReplace, filevar, filevar, %symbolB%, <i class='material-icons'>&#xE24E;</i>, All
StringReplace, filevar, filevar, %symbolC%, <i class='material-icons'>favorite</i>, All

FileDelete, page.html
FileAppend, %filevar%, page.html

return
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it enlightens also some other parts.

But acutally I am searching to use the (y) in Outlook2007 to insert some emojis into mails without having too much to search-click-enter

Comment: You haven't mentioned 'e-mail' or 'Outlook' on your question not even once; not even on the tags.